# Using searchlogic to sort associated model's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am using searchlogic for searching, pagination and sorting. My problem lies with sorting.

I have 2 models - submission and person.

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :person
end


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :submissions 
end
```

In my index.html.erb (for the submission controller), i have the code below for sorting:

```
<tr>
    <th> <%= order @search, :by => :SUB_ID, :as => "Submission Id" %></th>
    <th> <%= order @search, :by => :SUB_ENTRY_DATE, :as => "Creation Date" %> </th>
    <th> <%= order @search, :by => :SUB_TYPE, :as => "Submission Type" %> </th>
    <th> <%= order @search, :by => :PER_NAME??, :as => "Submitter Name" %> </th>
</tr>

<% @submissions.each do |submission| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h submission.SUB_ID %></td>
    <td><%=h submission.SUB_ENTRY_DATE %></td>
    <td><%=h submission.SUB_TYPE %></td>
    <td><%=h submission.person.PER_NAME %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Sorting the first 3 columns works because those fields are found in the submission table but i don't know how to sort the per_name column.

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searchlogic expects methods that look like this when ordering (eg):

`Submission.ascend_by_sub_type`

When using associations, you need to prefix the column name with the association name, so it should end up like:

`Submission.ascend_by_person_per_name`

Try using `:by => :person_per_name` in the order helper. That ought to generate the correct link.